# Edges of display are cut off, any way to tweek that?

Tags: display

The edges of the display are cut off.   I looked at a few of the other responses, but my TV doesn't have those settings for the display (I have an element TV).  I wouldn't really mind not seeing the full edges but it cuts off the time display and I can't tell the time.

Comment: What you are describing has nothing to do with Ubuntu or any of your software. If your **TV** is not showing the entire output, then it probably is using "overscan" and you need to disable it in your TVs settings. Your PC is sending the complete screen and your TV is throwing out the parts you can't see.

Comment: I can't find anything like "overscan" in the menu on the TV.  Only things in the picture menu are "contrast, color, brightness, sharpness, color temp. and blue screen"   Maybe I should get a new TV.

Comment: It might not be called overscan. Are you possibly using some analog component to connect the TV, like a VGA cable or adapter?

Comment: It's HDMI connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the overscan with xvidtune (from package x11-xserver-utils), but BE CAREFUL not to make big changes, you can ruin your monitor.   Basically play around with the sliders, then write out the modeline, and add it to an xorg.conf to make the changes permanent.

Comment: This would solve the immediate problem but it's kind of like fixing a leaky roof with a bucket. Unless it's a CRT, it would cause the image to appear blurred since it will not scale properly.  Overscan is a feature of the television (albeit a feature that nobody using it as a display wants), but I've never seen the overscan feature on a TV without the ability to disable it. I think OP should consult the TVs documentation or comb thru the settings more thoroughly